# App doesn't start when deployed on the market

Tags: android, deployment

I have an app that works on my device while debugging on Android Studio. It works too when I generate the apk copy it to my phone and install it from there. But it doesn't work anymore if i install it from the market.

I just have an error message "Unfortunately, xxxxx has stopped". I checked the crash report in Google Play Console but I have 0 crash, at least for now... Is there a way to get some crash log or some clue to debug this ?

Comment: without any **crash-log** or any **code** how we can give a solution my friend

Comment: I don't know, maybe it could be a known problem, or they is a way to get some crash-log since I have nothing in Google Developer Console. I unfortunately don't have any crash-log, i just hoped to have one in the crash report in Google Developer Console. The problem is I actually have no idea how to act or debug this since I have nothing...

Comment: That's why Crashlytics is a good idea. http://try.crashlytics.com/

Comment: Thank you @Rohit5k2  I gonna try that, I just thought there is always a crash report in Google console but looks like not....

Comment: It look like their "Get started with Crashlytics" button is crashing... hope they have some reports or logs :)

Comment: Just disable instance run then generate apk. upload new apk I think will work(90%) this was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install crashlytics or firebase crash dependencies and you'll be able to see the crash logs on their consoles. If you don't want that, you yourself can override the Thread.UncaughtexceptionHandler and set your custom handler as the default handler. Just Google how to do that as it's a lengthy thing to explain here.

Also if you are using proguard, firebase crash will need other configurations apart from just adding the dependency. Crashlytics handles this on its own.

Comment: Thank you, I'm on my way to install firebase crash. Hope it will helps. I'll let you know.

Comment: Looks like firebase console doesn't work and crash too..... I'm just geting a "There was an error completing your request" trying to go on my console. When I go on "get started with crashlytics" on Crashlytics website I'm just getting a blank screen, it looks like they have some problems on Crashlytics too right now. Looks like the world is against me today, maybe I should go back to sleep....

Comment: ok firebase console finally working, guess it was temporary problem.

Comment: Ya i guess that's a sign from the universe :) sleep... It's very easy to get these two to work dw :) you'll get there

Comment: Thanks, i got my error report from Firebase Crash and it's helping me a lot. I really though that the Developer Console get all crashes and we just can use firebase for more detailed ones.... it looks like it's not only this in some cases or maybe it's delayed. Actually my issue is quite serious "1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. ". So looks like my database is not there, that can be a problem :D I definitely go back to sleep now :)